# SpriteNode animation is failing

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have been trying to have a sprite with more than one texture so that it looks as if it was moving. I was looking at other questions and nothing they have done has fixed my issue, this is my code:

```
    var textures = [SKTexture]()
    for x in 0...2 {
        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "peng_" + String(x))
        textures.append(texture)
        print("pen_" + String(x))
    }
    let pen = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "peng_0")
    self.addChild(pen)
    let action = SKAction.animate(withNormalTextures: textures, timePerFrame: 0.1, resize: false, restore: true)
    pen.run(SKAction.repeatForever(action))
```

When I run the simulation, the sprite stays still with the "peng_0" texture, but I want it to iterate the other textures every 0.1s

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong, thanks.

Comment: You do not want restore=true,  the animation is moving so fast all you are seeing is the original texture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go set your code like this

```
    var array = ["R1", "R2", "R3", "R4", "R5", "R6", "R7", "R8"]
    var textures:[SKTexture] = []
    for i in 0 ..< array.count{
        let texture: SKTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: array[i])
        textures.insert(texture, at:i)
    }
   let pen = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "R1")
    self.addChild(pen)
    let animation = SKAction.animate(with: textures, timePerFrame: 8/60, resize: true , restore:false )
    pen.run =  SKAction.repeatForever(animation)
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! What is the difference between append and insert? And could you explain why my previous code wasn't working?

Comment: Append adds to the end of the array where insert adds it at the given index. When working with animations, I always use insert and set out all my image names first in an array although you could say doing that is more error prone as I could easily misspell one of the strings